# json.Marshal set null

Tags: go, synchronization, marshalling

I am new in Go. I'm trying to do scraper for the data from one my website, to be able to use it inside the Go app.

I using goroutines and sync.WaitGroup for waiting for results, but I have a problem. If I use goroutines and try to use json.Marshal for my dataset, I have empty array inside the structure, that is filling inside the goroutines.

If I am filling my structure without routines, I have everything  working well.

Here are my structures:

```
type CategoryScrapper struct {
    Name        string                `json:"name"`
    Link        string                `json:"link"`
    Products []Product.ProductData `json:"products"`
}

type ProductData struct {
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Link        string `json:"link"`
    Thumbnail   string `json:"thumbnail"`
    OriginPrice string `json:"OriginPrice"`
    Excerpt     string `json:"Excerpt"`
}
```

Here is a part of my app

```
func main() {
    cs := Category.CategoryScrapper{
        Name: "Name",
        Link: "/link",
    }

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    go cs.GetProducts(wg)
    wg.Wait()

    res, _ := json.Marshal(cs)

    fmt.Println(string(res))
}

func (s *CategoryScrapper) GetProducts(pool *sync.WaitGroup) {
    pool.Add(1)
    defer pool.Done()

    maxPageNum := s.getMaxPageNum()
    localPool := new(sync.WaitGroup)

    s.Products = make([]Product.ProductData, 0)

    for i := 1; i <= maxPageNum; i++ {
        go s.getPage(i, localPool)
    }

    localPool.Wait()
}

func (s *CategoryScrapper) getPage(page int, waitingPool *sync.WaitGroup) {
    product := Product.ProductData{
        Name: "Name",
        Link: "Link",
        Thumbnail: "Thumb",
        OriginPrice: "1111",
        Excerpt: "Excerpt",
    }

    s.Products = append(s.Products, product)
}
```

Comment: I have checked it now via debugging tools. `cs.Products` seems to be empty before marshalling, but why? And how can i fix it?

Comment: you need to call pool.Add() before calling `go cs.GetProducts` not inside GetProducts. Also localPool never seems to have Add or Done called on it, so its doing nothing.

Comment: @superfell I have removed part of method

Comment: @superfell thanks for idea, I will try

Comment: @superfell Yes, it's working. Thanks. But why I can't use `wg.Add` even if I pass it through by pointer? Could you explain?

Comment: You have a race condition on `s.Products = append(s.Products, product)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abstractions used here don't seem consistent for me. I'd just make the basic call to GetProducts a blocking call, then just use the wait group for when you need them. Once you simplify then you can see that there is no sync action happening where the data is written. (in getPage) so you do end up with nil

*Race condition fixed*

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type CategoryScrapper struct {
    Name     string        `json:"name"`
    Link     string        `json:"link"`
    Products []ProductData `json:"products"`
}

type ProductData struct {
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Link        string `json:"link"`
    Thumbnail   string `json:"thumbnail"`
    OriginPrice string `json:"OriginPrice"`
    Excerpt     string `json:"Excerpt"`
}

func (*CategoryScrapper) getMaxPageNum() int {
    return 1
}
func main() {
    cs := CategoryScrapper{
        Name: "Name",
        Link: "/link",
    }

    cs.GetProducts()

    res, err := json.Marshal(cs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(res))
}

func (s *CategoryScrapper) GetProducts() {
    maxPageNum := s.getMaxPageNum()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan ProductData)
    go func() {
        for p := range ch {
            s.Products = append(s.Products, p)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    for i := 1; i <= maxPageNum; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            ch <- s.getPage(i)
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    // make sure we close the chan reader go routine
    wg.Add(1)
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
}

func (s *CategoryScrapper) getPage(page int) ProductData {
    return ProductData{
        Name:        "Name",
        Link:        "Link",
        Thumbnail:   "Thumb",
        OriginPrice: "1111",
        Excerpt:     "Excerpt",
    }
}
```

A few stylistic points:
For your `Products` slice you don't need to initialise it to a zero length size, nil is find to append to.
I removed a number package prefixes like `Product` it helps people answer if you can get you example to run in play.golang.org easily

Hope this helps. It is only obvious when you've done it a few times, and even then, not always :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using `wg.Add` before routine is solved this problem

Comment: @Adam Straughan there is a race condition in the code you have provided as a solution.

Comment: Yes, there is. I would use channels rather than sharing state across the goroutines. If I have time I'll update the post

Comment: removed race condition . Probably,. I've not it tested properly, I'm on a train and a bit busy :-)

Comment: The `Wait`/`Add`/`close`/`Wait` is unnecessary. You can just `Wait` and then `close`.

Comment: @Adrian If you just wait and close, there is no guarantee that `s.Products = append(s.Products, p)` is executed before the program terminates. I suspect there is a neater way to do this though, feel free to submit a better version, I'd be interested (that sounds sarcastic, it's not meant to be :-) )

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the code. You should be doing the `Wait` and `close` in a goroutine, and the reads directly in `GetProducts`, instead of the other way around. This avoids the messy extra `Add`/`Wait` at the end.